# MySQL, get data based on two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data based on two tables.

My tables look like this:

```
table1:
    id | value | email

table2:
    id | category | value | email
```

I am trying to get all values of table 1, as long as they are not in table2 with the category of my variable (myVar).

**Example:**
Our Variable is "DontPickMe".
In table1 we have value 1,2,3. In table2 we have 1,2. Number 1 got category "keepMe" and number 2 got category "DontPickMe" (our variable). The result should now be: 1,3.

In the example (result should be 1,3):

```
table1:
        id | value | email
               1
               2
               3
table2:
        id | category | value | email
             keepMe       1
            DontPickMe    2
```

I tried the below but it is wrong.. How can I achieve this?

```
let sql = 'SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT category FROM table2 WHERE category = ?)';

    connection.query(sql, [myVar], function(error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between table1 and table2?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN for this.

Comment: you simply need a `!=` OR `not in`, do check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use this to get desired result

```
   let sql = 'SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE category = ?)';

  connection.query(sql, [myVar], function(error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct value FROM table1 left join  table2 on table1.category=table2.category
 WHERE table1.category = ? and table2.category is null

Answer (score 0):

```
let sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.value = table2.value WHERE category = ?';

    connection.query(sql, [myVar], function(error, result) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(result)
```

Sorry if wrong. :D

Comment: This is very close! In the example above (I have edited my question to make it easier to read) it gives me number 1, but not number 3. i cant understand how to also get the number 3.